# scaffold an admin CRUD in asp.net core web application 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to scaffold a CRUD admin in asp.net core. but the Application user class is not included in the model Classes listed.

I tried to create another class that does not inherit from identity user,

```
public class Investors
{

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Project { get; set; }

    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    }
```

When I  then tried to scaffold CRUD operation the investors model was listed in the model class.  i used it but When i run my project i am not able to see a list of already registered users.

This is the Application User class which i created.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Project { get; set; }

    public string Telephone { get; set; }
```

The Actual model class that would return a list of Already registered users  would have been the Application User class (but it is not listed while while Scaffolding CRUD razor page)since it was the one i used while creating the user.

Comment: Do you build your project before scaffolding a model? This is mandatory (also after every change to the model), because the list of models is taken from the **compiled** dll

Comment: yes i do. but still Application User model does not show up

Answer (score 1):

As my test, I could get the same result. It seems to be related with `Identity classes` which are defined for `Identity`.

IMO, you should avoid operating `ApplicationUser` by `DbContext` from controller directly.

For `ApplicationUser` which inherts from `IdentityUser`, the user will contains much properties like `ConcurrencyStamp` and `SecurityStamp`. If you create user directly from `Controller` by `DbContext`, you may miss set the values for them and that will cause your `Identity Feature` unstable.

There is no need to create a new Controller with `ApplicationUser`, you could use `AccountController` and `ManageController` to control the `ApplicationUser` in eariler than `Asp.Net Core 2.1`. For `Asp.Net Core 2.1` and later, you could try `Identity Scaffold` to custom the `Identity`.

For `ApplicationUser` with `CRUD`, you could create controller with injecting `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` .

Comment: I don't really see this as being an option without extending `UserManager` somehow *IF* you have also extended ApplicationUser with your own properties (as is the case in my situation.